# React Error - Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, components

Am following this tutorial on using fetch; I was able to pull the photos using this mock API: https://randomuser.me/api/    ...But modified the code to pull other data from the API e.g. first name. But, encountered an error in the process:

here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      pictures: [],
      people: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ pictures: data.results }))
    .then(data => this.setState({ people: data.results }));
  }



    render()  {
      console.log(this.state);
      return (
        <div>
            {
              this.state.pictures.map( pic =>(<div><img src={pic.picture.medium} /></div>) ).
              this.state.people.map(person => (<div>{person.name.first}</div>))
            }    
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default App;
```

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to pull more then just the pictures (other data from the API) and was not sure if I was on the right track. Currently, I'm trying to get the first name. Could I get some help with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the variable names you're using make sense given that the API response doesn't have anything called `pictures` or `people` in it.

What you want to do is set your data in state, and then loop over it.

In short, you'd have something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { data: [] }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.results }))
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return 'loading'
    }
    console.log(this.state.data)
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.data.map(item => (
            <div>
              <img src={item.picture.medium} />
              <p>{item.name.first}</p>
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

There's a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7apdpm).

Answer (score 1):

Each expression should be enclosed by `{}`.

```
{this.state.pictures.map(pic => (
  <div>
    <img src={pic.picture.medium} />
  </div>
))}
{this.state.people.map(person => <div>{person.name.first}</div>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response `data.results` is an array of object, where each object contain `name` property. You need to change your render function to display name

```
render()  {
  return (
    <div>
        {
          this.state.pictures.map(item =>(
          <div>
            <img src={item.picture.medium} />
            <div>{item.name.first}</div>
          </div>))
        }    
    </div>
  );
}
```

The name `pictures` that you have used to store the result is not appropriate, please take care of the naming part.

Hope this will help!